# How to use .Where in generic list

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a List(Of MyType) and I would like to use LINQ to get a subset of the list.

On MyType there's a field called AccountNumber. Can I use LINQ to say soemthing like this?

```
Dim t As List(Of MyType)
t = GetMyTypes()
t = t.Where(AccountNumber = "123")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're almost there. The argument of `Where` needs to be a *function*, so your code should look like this:

```
Dim t As List(Of MyType)
t = GetMyTypes()
Dim result = t.Where(Function(x) x.AccountNumber = "123")
```

Alternatively, you can use the verbose LINQ syntax:

```
Dim result = From t In GetMyTypes() Where t.AccountNumber = "123"
```

The data type returned is not a `List(Of MyType)` but an `IEnumerable(Of MyType)`, so you cannot directly assign it to a variable declared as `List(Of MyType)` . If you want to create a list, you can "convert" it by using `result.ToList()`. This would also cause the [list to be evaluated immediately](https://web.archive.org/web/20150821000301/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/04/lazy-evaluation-_2800_and-in-contrast_2c00_-eager-evaluation_2900_.aspx).

Comment: Not sure if it's okay to add to this... 
Wouldn't adding a .First to the .Where() make this a bit better?

Comment: @Feign: It really depends on what you want to achieve: If you want the **first** entry with account number `123`, use `First` (adding an `Order By` clause might be useful in that case, though). If you want **a list of all** entries with account number `123` , use `ToList`.